# How did "Metamorphosis Two" form the basis of one of the main musical themes in the film The Hours?

Tags: soundtrack

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Hours_(soundtrack) doesn't mention Metamorphosis Two. How "["Metamorphosis Two" formed the basis of one of the main musical themes in the film The Hours.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solo_Piano_(Philip_Glass_album))"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per the composer's website, in the credits to the soundtrack album:

> Music published by Famous Music Corporation (ASCAP), except the following, published by Dunvagen Music Publishers, Inc.: the first section of track 6, “‘I’m Going to Make a Cake,’” based on the theme from “Protest” (Act II, Scene 3) from the opera Satyagraha; track 11, “Tearing Herself Away,” based on “Islands” from the album Glassworks (not contained in the motion picture); **and track 12, “Escape,” based on “Metamorphosis Two” from the album Solo Piano.**

https://philipglass.com/recordings/hours/

Please note that Wikipedia is crowdsourced, it it not necessarily definitive. If you think this should be added to the referenced article, you should make the appropriate edit (be sure to add the appropriate citation).